# Wordpress Link Pagination to display only next and previous buttons

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am a bit of a WP noob so I am not sure how to go about this. I have a post where I want to display a list of images. However I want the users to be able to click next and previous so they can cycle through the images as if they are on different pages.

I added this bit of code to break up the post into multiple pages:

```
    <!--nextpage-->
```

Currently when I add this it displays  **1 2 3 Next** etc... then when you click next or one of the numbers it changes to **Previous 2 3** etc.. Is there a way to modify this so It only display next and previous and not the numbers inbetween?

I tried to modify this bit of code for the singlepost.php but every time I did I just ended up breaking it:

```
    <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<div class="pagination">', 'after' => '</div>', 'link_before'  => '<span class="current"><span class="currenttext">', 'link_after' => '</span></span>', 'next_or_number' => 'next_and_number', 'nextpagelink' => __('Next','mythemeshop'), 'previouspagelink' => __('Previous','mythemeshop'), 'pagelink' => '%','echo' => 1 )); ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi what i think you are looking for is this

```
<?php
global $page, $pages;

// If the current page equals the last page
if ($page == count($page)): 

  $previous_post = get_previous_post(); 
  // Then spit out the next link
  ?>
  <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $previous_post->ID ); ?>"><span style="float:left;" class="meta-item">Previous Gallery</span></a>
<?php
// End the if statement
endif;

wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div style="text-align: center;" class="page-link-next-prev">', 
'after' => '', 'previouspagelink' => '<span style="float:left;" class="meta-item">Previous post</span>', 'nextpagelink' => '', 
'next_or_number' => 'next' ) ); 

echo('<span style="text-align: center;">'.$page.' of '.count($pages).'</span>');

wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '', 'after' => '</div>', 'previouspagelink' => '', 
'nextpagelink' => '<span style="float:right;" class="meta-item">Next post</span>', 'next_or_number' => 'next' ) ); 
?>

<?php
// If the current page is first page
if ($page == count($pages)): 

  $next_post = get_next_post(); 
  // Then spit out the next link
  ?>
  <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $next_post->ID ); ?>"><span style="float:right;" class="meta-item">Next Gallery</span></a>
<?php
// End the if statement
endif; ?>
```